# Split a string and keep just one specific part

Tags: r, split, data.table

In my `data.table`, I use `tstrsplit` to split the ValueId column, with the `keep=` parameter. But in this case, I do not know the value to put in the `keep`, and I would like to use the value from the Level column.

All my attempts are failures. Is it possible ? Maybe not in `data.table` ?

Here is a reprex :

```
library(data.table)

foo <- data.table(Level = c(2,2,3,4,3),
                  ValueId = c("11983:1055521", "11983:1055521-5168:290668-198:100798", "11983:1055521-5168:290668-198:100798-92:91604-139:94569-135:94719-5161:290771-5162:290728-5166:290620",
                             "11983:1055521-5168:290668-198:100798-92:91604-139:94569-135:94719-5161:290771", " 11983:1055521-5168:290676-198:100794-92:91781-139:95090-135:95353"))

foo[, newvar := tstrsplit(ValueId, "-", fixed = TRUE, keep = 4)]

foo[, newvar := tstrsplit(ValueId, "-", fixed = TRUE, keep = Level)]
```

Thanks !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple problems.  One of them is in the `tstrsplit` function itself which is defined as:

```
function (x, ..., fill = NA, type.convert = FALSE, keep, names = FALSE) 
{
  if (!isTRUEorFALSE(names) && !is.character(names)) 
    stop("'names' must be TRUE/FALSE or a character vector.")
  ans = transpose(strsplit(as.character(x), ...), fill = fill, 
                  ignore.empty = FALSE)
  if (!missing(keep)) {
    keep = suppressWarnings(as.integer(keep))
    chk = min(keep) >= min(1L, length(ans)) & max(keep) <= 
      length(ans)
    if (!isTRUE(chk)) 
      stop("'keep' should contain integer values between ", 
           min(1L, length(ans)), " and ", length(ans), 
           ".")
    ans = ans[keep]
  }
  if (type.convert) 
    ans = lapply(ans, type.convert, as.is = TRUE)
  if (isFALSE(names)) 
    return(ans)
  else if (isTRUE(names)) 
    names = paste0("V", seq_along(ans))
  if (length(names) != length(ans)) {
    str = if (missing(keep)) 
      "ans"
    else "keep"
    stop("length(names) (= ", length(names), ") is not equal to length(", 
         str, ") (= ", length(ans), ").")
  }
  setattr(ans, "names", names)
  ans
}
<bytecode: 0x0000019bffd6da98>
  <environment: namespace:data.table>
```

The important thing to note is that `if` block that checks that your `keep` is the appropriate size for the return.  In your example you have the first row that returns NA.  The reason this works in your hard coded example is that `strsplit` is vectorized so the NA row is run at the same time as the rows that work so this `if` block doesn't get triggered.  You can try this out by changing that 4 to 40 and you'll get this message `Error in tstrsplit(ValueId, "-", fixed = TRUE, keep = 40) :  'keep' should contain integer values between 1 and 9.` because in that case nothing worked.

So what you need to do is redefine the `tstrsplit` function so that it'll return NA instead of stopping

```
tstrsplitNA<-function (x, ..., fill = NA, type.convert = FALSE, keep) 
{
  ans = transpose(strsplit(as.character(x), ...), fill = fill, 
                  ignore.empty = FALSE)
  if (!missing(keep)) {
    keep = suppressWarnings(as.integer(keep))
    chk = min(keep) >= min(1L, length(ans)) & max(keep) <= 
      length(ans)
    if (!isTRUE(chk)) 
      ans<-NA_character_
    ans = ans[keep]
  }
  if (type.convert) 
    ans = lapply(ans, type.convert, as.is = TRUE)
    return(ans)
  ans
}
```

That isn't enough though because `strsplit` is vectorized so doing `foo[, newvar := tstrsplitNA(ValueId, split="-", fixed = TRUE, keep = Level)]` isn't just running that function row by row but rather feeding the entirety of your `ValueId` column to `strsplit` and then transposing it which returns gibberish relative to what you want.

You can tell data.table to do the operation row by row simply by using the `by` argument with `Level` and `ValueId`

```
foo[, newvar := tstrsplitNA(ValueId, split="-", fixed = TRUE, keep = Level), by=c('Level','ValueId')]

foo
  Level                                                                                               ValueId      newvar
1:     2                                                                                         11983:1055521          NA
2:     2                                                                  11983:1055521-5168:290668-198:100798 5168:290668
3:     3 11983:1055521-5168:290668-198:100798-92:91604-139:94569-135:94719-5161:290771-5162:290728-5166:290620  198:100798
4:     4                         11983:1055521-5168:290668-198:100798-92:91604-139:94569-135:94719-5161:290771    92:91604
5:     3                                     11983:1055521-5168:290676-198:100794-92:91781-139:95090-135:95353  198:100794
```

Comment: Wouah let me book my day and learn from your answer !!

Comment: To make it work you just need the tstrsplitNA function and to use the `by` parameter.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `mapply` with `[` to extract the substring retuned by `strsplit` with the position given in `foo$Level`.

```
mapply(`[`, strsplit(foo$ValueId, "-", fixed = TRUE), foo$Level)
#[1] NA            "5168:290668" "198:100798"  "92:91604"    "198:100794"
```